# Allow public access for IAM role only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want only my beanstalk environment to access my S3 without any credentials or signed in URL's.

I have Beanstalk environment with EC2 instances attached with IAM role named  `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` .

I need the following

1.Public access like `curl http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html` without any signed url or secret keys , but it should be only done via instances which has role of `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` , how do I do that.

2.Also How do I  make sure this file transfer between EC2 and S3 is without internet , so that I don't get charged extra for accessing S3 via internet.

Following is what I tried

Right now I have following bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to access the url `http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html` via curl in EC2 instance , I get the error Access Denied

Comment: This is not possible. Anonymous requests like `curl http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html` do not include any identifying information, so it is not possible to know what IAM Role the caller has. You could restrict it via IP address in a Bucket Policy (with an Elastic IP on the calling instance), but this does not use an IAM Role.

Comment: Any services communicating within the same Region (eg Amazon EC2 instance to Amazon S3) does not incur any Data Transfer charges. Traffic within AWS does not go via the Internet (although it will go on the 'public edge' of the Internet within AWS infrastructure). There is a 1c/GB charge for traffic that goes in/out of a VPC via a public IP address, which could be avoided by using an S3 Gateway.

Comment: HI , I have created endpoint in VPC and I used the Endpoint VPC id in my bucket policy , now its working fine.